# Getting Http 500 error after while in laravel

Tags: html, laravel, while-loop, http-error

i'm trynig to display the disponibility of a user , with start time and end time , when i'm trying to add the Break time between the start and the end time with the while loop , this error appear: HTTP 500 error . This is The controller :

public function rdv( $ID)

```
{
     $model=doc::findOrFail($ID);
     $ReturnArray = array ();// Define output
     $StartTime    = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[0]) ; //Get Timestamp
     $EndTime      = strtotime ($model->Lun_apres_a[1]); //Get Timestamp
     $break_start = strtotime ($model->Lun_mat_de[1]) ; // break start
     $break_end   = strtotime ($model->Lun_apres_a[0]);// break end
     $breakConditions = ($StartTime <= $break_start) || ($EndTime >=$break_end) ;
     $duration = '60';
     $AddMins  = $duration * 60;

          do //Run loop
        {
            $ReturnArray[] = date("G:i", $StartTime );
            $StartTime  += $AddMins; //Endtime check
        }  
        while ($breakConditions) ;

        return view ('/rendezvous')->with([
            'go'=> $model, 
            'disponibility'=>$ReturnArray, 
        ]); 
}
```

This is the view :

```
<div class="card-header">
<img src="{{asset ('assets/img/uploads/'.$go->Photo)}}" alt="" class="profile-img">

<div class="col-6">
<h2> <strong> Dr. {{$go -> Nom}} {{$go -> Prénom}} </strong> </h2>
<h3> {{$go-> Spécialité}} </h3>
<h6 class="city"> Adresse cabinet : {{$go->Adresse_Cabinet}} </h6>
<h6 class="city"> Ville : {{$go-> Ville}} </h6>
<p class="full-name"> Qualification professionnelle :</p>
<h6 class="city"> Spécialité: {{$go-> Spécialité}} </h6>
<h6 class="city"> Diplome : {{$go-> Diplome}} </h6>
<p class="full-name"> Informations pratiques :</p>
<h6 class="city"> Mode de réglement : {{$go-> mr}} </h6>
<h6 class="city"> Assurance maladie : {{$go-> ass_m}} </h6>
 </div>
<div class="col-6">
<p class="full-name"> Les horaires: </p>
<div class="div1" ></div>
@foreach($jaja as $ja)
<button class="btn btn-info"> {{$ja}} </button> </br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you check your logfiles in storage/logs? Besides that I would suggest to use Carbon in Laravel, instead of the date function.

Comment: @ThomasV what i must do ?

Comment: every time you have posted this question someone points out that your loop never ends

Comment: In your Laravel project go to the "storage" folder and "logs", open the latest logfile.. or simply change debug to TRUE in your .env file, if you're in development mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. `$breakConditions` is not reevaluated each iteration as you seem to assume - at this point it is already known **constant value** and any changes to `$StartDate` etc are irrelevant. You need to change

```
do {
.... 
} while ($breakConditions);
```

to

```
do {
... 
} while (($StartTime <= $break_start) || ($EndTime >=$break_end));
```

PS: You should also consider following some coding style, incl. variable naming scheme as what you currently have is `mess style`.